# How to handle traversing in CustomItem of J2ME in a mobile phone which does not support traversing?

Tags: java-me, midp, lcdui, traversal

How to handle traversing in CustomItem of J2ME in a mobile phone which does not support traversing?

I am doing a mobile application using J2ME - MIDP 2.0. In my application I draw the table using `javax.microedition.lcdui.CustomItem`. I also implement the `traverse` method. But in some mobile phones the traversing is not supported. How to implemnent the traversing process in a mobile which does not support traversing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution for the problem.

First we find the device does support traversing or not by the method "getInteractionModes()" of the class "javax.microedition.lcdui.CustomItem".From that we get the traversing support or not.

If traversing is not support means then add a Command button for that then implement the traversing operation inside the button click event handling ( public void commandAction(Command c, Item item) ).

finding the device support traversing or not is shown in the following coding snippet

```
int supported_interaction_modes=this.getInteractionModes();
boolean horizontal_interaction,vertical_interaction;

if((supported_interaction_modes&CustomItem.TRAVERSE_HORIZONTAL)!=0)
  horizontal_interaction=true;
else
  horizontal_interaction=false;

if((supported_interaction_modes&CustomItem.TRAVERSE_VERTICAL)!=0)
  vertical_interaction=true;
else
  vertical_interaction=false;
```

In the above coding snippet "this" refers to the child class of CustomItem (javax.microedition.lcdui.CustomItem) which is user-defined class for CustomItem operations.